# ui-select does not display selected item

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0a36Cj257x2CunhyqiHl?p=preview) where
I am binding ui-select to list of items defined in controller like this:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
  var vm = this;   
  vm.tester = 1;
  vm.listItems = [
    { label: "aaa", value: 0, },
    { label: "bbb", value: 1, },
  ];    
});
```

And this is ui-select:

```
  <ui-select reset-search-input="true"
             ng-model="ctrl.tester">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="">
          {{$select.selected.text}}
      </ui-select-match>

      <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in ctrl.listItems | filter: { label: $select.search }">
          <span ng-bind-html="item.label" title="{{item.label}}"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

The problem is that although ctrl.tester contains selected value, selected value is not displayed in ui-select.

I must be missing something very obvious but cannot find what.

Comment: cannot see tester scope variable defined in controller anywhere .Please add complete code

Comment: @RahulB: no matter whether it's defined or not. but anyway i added it to code and problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your html to use `{{$select.selected.label}}`
instead of `{{$select.selected.text}}`

```
<ui-select reset-search-input="true"
             ng-model="ctrl.listItems.selected">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="">
          {{$select.selected.label}}
      </ui-select-match>

      <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in ctrl.listItems | filter: { label: $select.search }">
          <span ng-bind-html="item.label" title="{{item.label}}"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: thanks a million man :) I knew it's some typo error, but couldn't find it. sometimes it's too big to see :)

Comment: @jabko87 : No issues. You can remove the tester variable altogether and use listitems only for selected.